# How should I store API URLs in Android, if they are dependent on locale?

Tags: android

Right now they are just stored on a class called `Globals` as static fields. 
I'm not the one who made the app, but I am considering putting them in localized `strings.xml` files, such as `<string name="API_URL">http://someurl</string>`. Is this good or bad practice?

**UPDATE:**
I chose the answer that I feel answers the question most comprehensibly.
But after some re-thinking, I have chosen a different solution alltogether.
Given that URLs are actually based on the country which the app should be distributed for, it doesn't make sense to switch them based on locale, as the URLs should stay the same regardless of the language on the phone.
Instead, I have implemented Gradle Flavors, which create different APKs based on different settings and such. It allows you to create variations of the same app with the small changes that you need. :) So now I have the URLs in a flavor-specific file.

Thank you to everyone who took their time to comment and help me.

Comment: It is good, you may also create base class for same.

Comment: In what scenario would a url depend on the locale?

Comment: i dont recommend it, that's because if you later will need to change a URL you will need to change all the string in each values localized folder.
It's better to have a general base URL string as static field and build the localized ones at runtime using a dedicated method/class

Comment: @TimCastelijns, well, i don't understand the reason fully, but the backend developers have decided it's best with entirely different urls for each language. I didn't understand the reason enough to be able to explain it, but I understood it enough to acknowledge it :) so the different URLs will return the data needed for each language. Since I am not the one making the decision, it is just my job to make it work.

Comment: @MatPag
It will be unique for each language either way, so no matter how I look at it, that's not the issue.
Although, as for your suggestion, what do you mean by "build the localized ones at runtime"? How exactly could I do this? Have my class check for locale and assign the appropriate value? The variables right now are static constants, so I guess I'd have to rewrite the class for that to happen.

Comment: @NikkiTune can you provide us a fake url with the format that it's used to localize the urls? something like: myurl.com/api/en/rest/ or similar

Comment: @MatPag,
Not quite sure what you mean. 
Basically we have our current API url, which could be
`first.apiurl.com/something/rest?params`
once we go live with our product in other countries, we might have:
`arbitrary.arbitraryapiurl.com/something/rest?params` 
Or
`arbitrary2.arbitraryapiurl2.com/something/rest?params` 
And so on.... 

So basically it's only the base URL that changes... I have to call those urls to get data in the language that is set on the phone. 

I hope that clarified things a little bit? :)

Comment: @NikkiTune Yes, this clarify the things a bit, based on what you said i would suggest to your backend to use a base url and use subdomain for localize the API. To create URL of this type: en.baseurl.com/api/rest1, de.baseurl.com/api/rest1 and so on. In this way you can use a static base url and static endpoints and prefix them whit the 2-letters standard for each language supported. Obvisouly you will need to create a class to perform this runtime appending operations but should be easy enough. Developing with demo URLs you provided seems to me an architecture problem

Comment: @MatPag, I know that that would be the easy way :) But the powers that be say it cant be so .... even the baseurls are completely different.

Comment: @NikkiTune If you are forced to use bad URLs i think that putting them in string resources or storing them in java constants it's the same thing... 
Maybe you can try to build the endpoints at runtime (if at least them are the same over different baseurls) but nothing more. Good Luck, you will need it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with puneet, it's neither good nor bad. It depends on what you are doing with the API Urls.

Are you going to append them later with user input? If so I would suggest you keep them as global variables that way you can modify the API URL programatically as needed.

If the API Url are complete and will not need to be appended then putting them in the strings.xml would be fine. Just remember that you would still have to create a local String variable in the java to hold the text from the API_URL in the string.xml, which seems inefficient if what you're aiming for is to write less code.

Comment: If this, if that. Better ask the OP for clarification and base your answer on that, rather than guessing

Comment: Tim, that's why I gave options and descriptions for both of the answers I provided. To let to OP decide which is appropriate. And until the OP decides to give us more info guessing at their intent is all that is available.

Comment: Right now, the entire URL is put together by a `String.format()` call... So all data needed, including the base URL is being put together by that function... so in my mind, it doesn't matter if it comes from a string file or the global class. I could be wrong though :) Im still new'ish to android development.

Comment: Nikki, in the String.format() you're using do have any input from the user added to the API URL? By input I mean text from an edittext, options from a filter menu, or some other kind of user input that helps refine the API URL call?

Comment: @OvidioReyna, sometimes, yes.

Comment: My experience has been that making it a Global static variable makes it easier to work with when appending user input to the base String API URL.

Comment: @OvidioReyna, well I like your comprehensive answer :) 
After some thinking and discussing with backenders however, I actually think that maybe I'll have to make entirely country specific apps o_o which I don't know how to do yet, so that's another question. The problem lies in that, if say a Swedish person uses the Swedish app, they'd have to be able to use the Swedish API URL regardless of what the locale is set as on their phone xD So I think there was a slight thinking error on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Neither good nor bad.If your concern is the security then none of them provide the security as decompilation is possible.

Comment: Why is it not good nor bad? Security was not mentioned so it makes no sense to base an answer on that

Comment: Security in a (supposed) simple context it's the same, after opening the APK it's not hard to find a string resource or a static final URL...